# ¿Cómo puedo implementar la instrucción [0x28] (call) a una Máquina Virtual de Stack?

Tags: c#

Estoy implementando una VM (Máquina Virtual por sus siglas en inglés 'Virtual Machine') en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) basada en 'Stack' o Stack-Based (lo siento, no sé como se le llama al término en español).

La VM tiene varias instrucciones implementadas y me faltan algunas, entre ellas la `0x28` (*call*) que lo que hace es que [Llama al método indicado por el descriptor del método que se ha pasado.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp)

La VM esta basada en un [proyecto](https://github.com/TortegaFR/StackBasedVirtualMachine) de código abierto, así que si desea puede pasar por el github y bajarse la fuente y así tener un espacio mas dinámico para poder realizar lo que necesite, si es que tiene que implementar/aplicar código o probarlo de alguna manera.

Saludos y gracias por cualquier ayuda, de antemano, que me pueda brindar.

*Nota: Sépase que no subí código alguno ya que todo lo que tengo y he hecho esta bajo el mismo proyecto que mencioné mas arriba.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes implementar CALL y RET apilando el IP antes de hacer el salto y desapilándolo al regresar. Aquí una maqueta muy básica:

```
    public void CALL(string to)
    {
        stack.Push(ip + 1);
        ip = int.Parse(to); // igual que JMP
    }

    public void RET()
    {
        ip = stack.Pop(); // igual que JMP
    }
```

Ahora debes tener cuidado con lo que apilas para no sobreescribir el IP. Tal vez tengas que implementar otra pila diferente a la pila de datos. Aparte necesitas una tabla de traducción etiquetas/direcciones. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Call lo que hace es ir a una dirección de memoria, pues tendrás que hacer algo parecido a eso, pero según veo tu código, mas bien sería ir a una linea, por que no lo tienes estructurado de forma que se asemeje a direcciones de memoria. Otra forma, sería poner una especia de:

```
MI_FUNCION: // Aquí guardar este punto en una lista de funciones
ADD EAX,1 
xx..
... 
CALL MI_FUNCION // Mover el índice de ejecución a la función
```